# Problems with my Firefox addon and cross domain https

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, cors

I have an addon for Firefox which modifies a page at http://target.com with data from http://data.com. It does this by making an XMLHttpRequest() in the addon javascript and modifying the webpage accordingly. Neither the target nor the source servers are under my control.

This all worked fine until the target.com website changed to using https. As I was loading data from an http: address I got the following error:

> Blocked loading mixed active content

Fortunately data.com also supports https, so I changed the data lookup address to https://data.com, and then I got

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://data.com

I read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts#Cross-domain_XMLHttpRequest) that I could add the following to my package.json

```
  "permissions": {
      "cross-domain-content": ["https://data.com"]
  }
```

And now I don't get any errors, but the Developer Tools Network page doesn't show any connections being made.

Have I hit a dead end? I understand that CORS requires server support but I assumed that as it worked prior to the target server moving to https it would still work now.

Cheers

Rich

Comment: Are you running NoScript? Are you using JavaScript for your XHR or Firefox API? Is the XHR being made in page scope or browser scope?

Comment: HI @erosman - Not running NoScript, using JS for my XHR and the XHR is being made in page scope (I *believe*). I must stress that nothing else has changed apart from the site my addon is acting on has moved to using https (and some minor DOM changes whih shouldn't have introduced this).

Comment: Is your addon on AMO? If so where? I will have  a look

Comment: @erosman - cheers, much appreciated. You can find the last working version here (I haven't published the changes I outlined above as didn't see the point in publishing a known broken version). https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nomorvom/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is one of the issues with using libraries (and not Firefox API)

Try using the native Firefox API eg: [Connecting to Remote Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Connecting_to_Remote_Content)

Native Firefox API runs in the browser scope so there is no CORS to consider.

Comment: Excellent, thanks, I'll try that this evening and report back =)

Comment: `The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed.` i got this error after i used link code